# http connection timesout when running from commandline

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, httpurlconnection

I developed a java code to connect to a device and issue few `POST` commands. This runs well in `eclipse`. But when I build and run on `command-line` it always times out.

I am running `eclipse` in the same machine as command line .I am using `java 8`.

Comment: Consider sharing some of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network problems are best tackled by first keeping Java out of it. So as a first step, you can open up the console and try to do a telnet connection to the socket address you used in your program by entering

```
telnet targetserver.example.com 12345
```

If that times out as well, the source of your problem is not within Java.

You haven't provided much (e.g. source as requested) but my guess into the blue is that you're sitting behind a proxy that is configured in Eclipse. Eclipse passes that information to the started application so the connection works. Starting the application on the console lacks this information, so the network connection is attempted directly without going via the proxy.